# Similar masses and lifetimes of the $\Delta$ baryons

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, isospin-symmetry

Why do the four spin 3/2 $\Delta$ baryons have nearly identical masses and lifetimes despite their very different $u$ and $d$ quark compositions?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113252/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of $u\leftrightarrow d$  [isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) symmetry. For a more detailed explanation, see e.g. chapter 8 of ['t Hooft's lecture notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg.html). The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf).

Comment: What prereqs are there for understanding those notes? I really need to start formally learning QM,GR,QFT, &c, and this looks like a good place to start..

Comment: 't Hooft's notes are really about _Lie groups._ I would recommend as a prerequisite any QM course which studies at some length angular momentum operators and their commutation relations.

Comment: ...and/or a solid background in group theory.

Comment: @Qmechanic I was talking about all of his lecture notes, sorry about that (http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/GtH_lectures.html). Is there any online resource to learn the prereqs? I don't understand this operator business, and I know what tensors are, but very little as to how they can be used (covariance, contravariance, etc). I have a similar situation with group theory: I know what it is, but not its details. And I can't find any place that explains the whole thing starting from the basics.