# $\Delta^+$ decay in GZK process

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics, cosmic-microwave-background, pions, isospin-symmetry

The dominant channels in the [GZK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit) process are

$$p+\gamma_{\rm CMB}\to\Delta^+\to p+\pi^0,$$
$$p+\gamma_{\rm CMB}\to\Delta^+\to n+\pi^+.$$

According to the [pdg](http://pdg.lbl.gov/), $\Delta\to N+\pi$ makes up essentially 100% of the branching ratio (BR). It doesn't, however, say which process is favored: the proton and neutral pion or neutron and charged pion. My instinct is that they should each contribute about 50%, but I am not sure. So my question is, what are the BRs for each of the processes described above?

Comment: Interesting question! Note that the final-final states, after the neutrons and pions have decayed, are $$\begin{align*}p + \gamma_\text{CMB} &\to p + 2\gamma \\ p + \gamma_\text{CMB} &\to p + (e^- + \bar\nu_e) + (e^+ + \nu_e + \nu_\mu),\end{align*}$$ so the neutron channel probably contributes much more to the softening of the proton cosmic ray spectrum.

Comment: @rob Thanks, but I am interested more in the exact decay process not the total softening. That is, how often does which process occur? Google-fu has not turned up anything as everyone just seems to talk about nucleons and pions rather than their charges.

Comment: Some relevant calculations as comment; I'm not quite sure about the appropriate wording to formulate an entire answer: With suitable isospin [CL coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#j1.3D1.2C_j2.3D1.2F2)$$p+\pi^0\equiv |1/2,1/2\rangle\,|1,0\rangle=\sqrt{2/3}~|3/2,1/2\rangle-\sqrt{1/3}~|1/2,1/2 \rangle,$$and$$n+\pi^+ \equiv|1/2,-1/2\rangle\,|1,1\rangle=\sqrt{1/3}~|3/2,1/2\rangle+\sqrt{2/3}~|1/2,1/2\rangle.$$The branching ratio is thereby $$\frac{\Delta^+\rightarrow p+\pi^0}{\Delta^+\rightarrow n+\pi^+}\approx (\sqrt{2/3}~/\sqrt{1/3})^2=2.$$

Comment: @user12262 Thanks. I am assuming that you are using the fact that the Delta is a $|3/2,1/2\rangle$ particle, correct? It is a long time since I have done Clebsch-Gordon so I will have to refresh myself on this. Seeing that the ratio is $\mathcal O(1)$ is encouraging.

Comment: jazzwhiz: "_I am assuming that you are using the fact that the Delta is a $|3/2,1/2 \rangle$ particle_" -- The $\Delta^+$, right. (Also, I didn't point that out explicitly in my above comment since I had been using up pretty much all of the permitted 600 characters already &). "_It is a long time since I have done Clebsch-Gordon_" -- Same here. ($\approx$ 20 years since I first and last saw the similar problem of calculating $\frac{ \sigma(p \pi^+ \rightarrow p \pi^+)}{\sigma(p \pi^- \rightarrow p \pi^-)}$ etc.). So I'm a bit hesitant to "argue away" the remaining $|1/2,1/2 \rangle$ parts ...

Comment: All the reported measurements seem to have been made in pi N -> pi N scattering. Since this would mean the scattering off a nuclear matter target containing protons and neutrons, probably iron or lead, it would be difficult to extract separate decay / production rates. Possibly, this could be extracted from the ratio of final state protons to neutrons, but there are probably shell structure subtleties (i.e. is the pi P production fraction really = Z/A?).

Comment: @jwimberley Good point. Theory it is then (which is what I had suspected). I don't need something with precision, just one decimal place will do.

Comment: p.s. Above I wrote mistakenly "CL coefficients", while I meant "[Clebsch-Gordan coefficients; a.k.a. CG coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#j1.3D1.2C_j2.3D1.2F2)". Note how to spell the name of [Paul Gordan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Gordan), btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [...] $\Delta^+ \rightarrow p + \pi^0$, [...] $\Delta^+ \rightarrow n + \pi^+$,
>
> which process is favored: the proton and neutral pion or neutron and charged pion [?]

Since the kinematics (and corresponding "phase space" factors) for the two final states are presumably as good as equal, the evaluation of the branching ratio

$$\text{BR} := \frac{\Gamma[ \Delta^+\rightarrow p+\pi^0 ]}{\Gamma[ \Delta^+\rightarrow n+\pi^+ ]}$$

simplifies to determining the ratio of "state constituent" transition probabilities

$$\text{BR} := \frac{\Gamma[ \Delta^+\rightarrow p+\pi^0 ]}{\Gamma[ \Delta^+\rightarrow n+\pi^+ ]} \simeq \frac{\left\lvert \langle p; \pi^0 \mid \Delta^+ \rangle \right\rvert^2}{\left\lvert \langle n; \pi^+ \mid \Delta^+ \rangle \right\rvert^2}.$$

Analyzing (or defining) the initial state $\Delta^+$ and the two distinct final states in terms of [isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) leads to the expressions

$$ \lvert \Delta^+ \rangle \equiv \big\lvert \left(3/2, 1/2\right)_i \big\rangle, $$

where the first value represents the magnitude of $\mathbf I$, and the second value represents the magnitude of $I_3$, along with

$$ \lvert p; \pi^0 \rangle \equiv \big\lvert (1/2, 1/2)_f; (1, 0)_f \big\rangle \equiv \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} }~\big\lvert (3/2, 1/2)_t \big\rangle - \sqrt{ \frac{1}{3} }~\big\lvert (1/2, 1/2)_t \big\rangle, $$ and

$$ \lvert n; \pi^+ \rangle \equiv \big\lvert (1/2, -1/2)_f; (1, 1)_f \big\rangle \equiv \sqrt{ \frac{1}{3} }~\big\lvert (3/2, 1/2)_t \big\rangle + \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} }~\big\lvert (1/2, 1/2)_t \big\rangle, $$

where

- the coefficients of the linear combinations on the right-hand sides are [Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) (specificly those values listed in table ["$1/2 \otimes 1$"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#j1.3D1.2C_j2.3D1.2F2)),
- all states are normalized, and
- the indices $f$ and $t$ are to distinguish final states and "state representations to evaluate transition probabilities"; such that in particular the states $(1/2, 1/2)_f$ and $(1/2, 1/2)_t$ are (meant to be) distinct; and both are distinct, and indeed disjoint, from the initial state $\lvert \Delta^+ \rangle \equiv \lvert (3/2, 1/2)_i \rangle$.

Now identifying

$$\big\lvert (3/2, 1/2)_t \big\rangle \equiv \big\lvert (3/2, 1/2)_i \big\rangle $$

we can evaluate

\begin{align}
\langle p; \pi^0 \mid \Delta^+ \rangle & \equiv \bigg\langle \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} }~ (3/2, 1/2)_t - \sqrt{ \frac{1}{3} }~ (1/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\vert (3/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\rangle \\
& = \bigg\langle \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} }~ (3/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\vert (3/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\rangle \\
& = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} }
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\langle n; \pi^+ \mid \Delta^+ \rangle & \equiv \bigg\langle \sqrt{ \frac{1}{3} }~ (3/2, 1/2)_t + \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} }~ (1/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\vert (3/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\rangle \\
& = \bigg\langle \sqrt{ \frac{1}{3} }~ (3/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\vert (3/2, 1/2)_t \bigg\rangle \\
& = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{3} }
\end{align}

obtaining the sought branching ratio value as

$$\text{BR} := \frac{\Gamma[ \Delta^+\rightarrow p+\pi^0 ]}{\Gamma[ \Delta^+\rightarrow n+\pi^+ ]} \simeq \frac{ (\sqrt{ 2/3 })^2 }{ (\sqrt{ 1/3 })^2} = 2.$$

Comment: The initial version of this answer has been formulated based on the comments of user12262 to the OP question above; and in consideration of [remarks stated there (meta)](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/give-an-answer-or-comment-instead).

Comment: That specific branching ratio is also discussed in Chapter 8, eq. (8.11) of these ['t Hooft's lecture notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg.html). The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf).

Comment: @user12262 I also threw in some formatting. If I clobbered it too much, just roll back the edit.

Comment: @Qmechanic: "_That specific branching ratio is also discussed in Chapter 8, eq. (8.11) of these 't Hooft's lecture notes. [ www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf (p. 46) ]_" -- With the same result (eq. 8.11:$$ \Gamma[\Delta^+\rightarrow n~\pi^+] : \Gamma[\Delta^+\rightarrow p~\pi^0] = 1 : 2$$), thank goodness. A bit above (on that same page) 't Hooft refers to `two different irreducible representations of the isospin group` in default of which the present version of this answer had coined the phrase "state representations to evaluate transition probabilities". Close enough, I suppose ...

Comment: @Chris White: "_I also threw in some formatting. [...]_" -- Exemplary, IMHO; I like it a lot, FWIW. (Indeed: honestly [**nothing but** formatting thrown in](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/126851/revisions), too...) I recall my frustration when logging in here for the very first time (or was it even right before that) that I was not (yet) permitted to read the source "code" of answers (nor comments); so I felt unable to match some essential ways of formatting. (I'll check if at least `community wiki` source content is readable without login. (How to search for `community wiki`, btw. ?))

Comment: @rob ("user 44126") -- I just noticed (with much surprise) that I have been awared the `300` as reputation which [you had invested as `bounty` on Jul 16, 2014](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/44126/rob?tab=reputation). I like to point out that I had submitted my answer as (my very first) `community-wiki` under the assumption that "[_Community wiki posts ... do not confer any reputation._](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)". (Reflecting on how I had earned my reputation points until then I considered "+300" pretty much an utterly disproportionate amount.)

Comment: @user12262 I wasn't sure what would happen to the bounty since the only new answer was a community wiki. I put a big bounty on the question because I wasn't expecting such a straightforward solution. If you think the reward was disproportionate, feel free to award some "exceptional answer" bounties to some posts that you liked better. Cheers!