# What is the branching fraction of the $\Delta^0$?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, isospin-symmetry

I've been looking for a literature value and can't find one, even from the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/). Does anyone know where I could find the branching fractions for the $\Delta^0$ decay modes, specifically $\Delta^0 \rightarrow n + \pi^0$ $\Delta^0 \rightarrow p + \pi^-$?

Comment: See eq. (8.14) in ['t Hooft's lecture notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg.html). The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf). Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20999/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113252/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except for small electromagnetic decay branching ratios like $\Delta\to N\gamma$, essentially 100% of the branching ratio of the $\Delta$ is to $N\pi$ final states. This is just kinematics. The only other hadronic final state with baryon number one that is energetically allowed is $N\pi\pi$, which has an extremely small phase (it is just barely allowed).

The relative rates for $\Delta^0\to n+\pi^0$ and $\Delta^0\to p+\pi^-$ are determined by isospin. The relevant Clebsch-Gordon coefficients are
$$
\langle 3/2,-1/2|1/2,-1/2;1,0\rangle = \sqrt{2/3}\\
\langle 3/2,-1/2|1/2,1/2;1,-1\rangle = \sqrt{1/3}
$$
so the relative rates are 2/3 and 1/3.

Answer (score 3):

The  [resonance](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/tables/rpp2012-tab-baryons-Delta.pdf) has an isospin and as a strong interaction resonance, the decay channels are  treated in the PDG as one "Nucleon pi" decay

[image: delta1232]

The correct ratio is given in the answer by @Thomas, who gives the algebra of the SU(2) isospin case. 2:1

Comment: This is not right. The rates are determined by Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, which are 2:1.

Comment: @Thomas  yes, the way to get the numbers are clebsch gordan coefficients, I just guessed at them because I am too rusty.

Comment: OP please choose the other answer as the correct one as I had a mistaken ratio . You are allowed to change mind on which answer you chose. Sorry if this was a homeork problem, but in any case for a homework problem you have to show the calculation

Comment: Not a homework problem and it's all right, I was only looking for these as confirmation of a calculation, I had used CG coefficients.