# The existence of Delta baryons was experimentally proven?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, mass, baryons

If we will look at the [table from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_baryon) of their properties, we will find the same mass for all. That looks like a result of some calculation, rather then a result of measurement. Was that important particles really found?

[image: delta baryons]

Comment: To see something similar in mid-1950s and to have well studied partricles is different, is not?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20999/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113252/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Did you check the [PDG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_Data_Group)?

Comment: Yes. Not even a single mention of delta++. http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-tab-baryons-Delta.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Similar masses and lifetimes of the $\Delta$ baryons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20999/)

Comment: Yes, agree, really duplicate question, and formally there is 1 answer to previos question. What it is better in this situation? May be it is better to me to delete the question?

Comment: "Not even a single mention of delta++" You're probably confusing parity and charge. They don't bother listing the four different charges because of isospin symmetry. $\Delta^{++}$ are well observed

Comment: But where is delta++ in the table of PDG?  http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-tab-baryons-Delta.pdf

Comment: Please re-read my comment. All of the $\Delta$ states listed in that document include the $\Delta^-$, $\Delta^0$, $\Delta^+$ and $\Delta^{++}$ versions. The four different charges are not explicity stated because isospin symmetry makes it redundant: it would just be the same information repeated 4 times over.

Comment: Thank you very much, dukwon, for explanation, that is really not obvious, as in other tables of PDG information is really duplicated and all properties of particles are listed.

Comment: No, in other tables they also don't bother duplicating information where isospin symmetry makes it redundant e.g. the heavier $\pi, \rho, a$ and $b$ states in http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-tab-mesons-light.pdf and all of the excited $K^{(*)}$ states in http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-tab-mesons-strange.pdf

Comment: Thank you, dukwon for a help. I am lookin in the table and still cannot understand. Several variants with I = +3/2 J = +3/2. Decays are similar, Nπ usually dominates. Which one doubly charged particle \Delta^{++}? Which one?